# Handle breadcrumbs in mvc dotnetcore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, breadcrumbs

I'm working on a website `(MVC dotnetcore)` that has many pages and flows as well. A user can approach a single page from many different ways. I'm getting stuck when user wants to move back and I don't have any track of its last URL. And **I'm getting confused that how to handle this situation?**

> Should I use a global variable to keep track of last URL??

but in this case, I've to do a repeatable code on each screen, or may be for each get/ post call.

OR

> Should I use kind of breadcrumbs structure?

Like if user move Admin from Index, there would be something like this

```
Index >> Admin
```

And for further

```
Index >> Admin >> ManageUsers
```

And these would be links to their related pages.
**But I dont know how to handle this in mvc dotnetcore? Any Idea??**

Which approach is good to follow? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

I know the answer is a bit old, but I got the same problem when I was creating websites. I didn't want to repeat code in both projects and I wanted the breadcrumbs to handle multiple levels, especially levels that aren't in the same Controller. I ended up creating a little package to manage all of this: [SmartBreadcrumbs](https://github.com/zHaytam/SmartBreadcrumbs) (available in Nuget).

It's very easy to use, all you need to do is:

1. In your services configuration, add
   `services.UseBreadcrumbs(GetType().Assembly);`
2. Add `[DefaultBreadcrumb("My home")]` to your default node (usually the Home)
3. Add `[Breadcrumb("Contact me", FromAction = "Index" FromController = typeof(HomeController))]` to your other levels (FromAction can be any combination of Controller.Action)

PS: The default node is ALWAYS present, even without specifying `FromAction`.
More informations on the github link or [Blog post](https://blog.zhaytam.com/2018/06/24/asp-net-core-using-smartbreadcrumbs/).

EDIT: Updated examples for version 2.0.0

Comment: Note: In SmartBreadCrumbs v2.0.0 you must use `[DefaultBreadcrumb("My home")]` attribute or an exception is thrown!

Comment: Hi @Leigh, I edited the example I made for version 2.0.0, thanks!

Comment: I've given SmartBreadcrumbs a try with a new aspnetcore project. One downside for me is that you have to manually specify the breadcrumb title for each page with a [Breadcrumb] attribute. I'd hoped if you didn't specify the attribute it would infer the breadcrumb name from the page name, which would save some effort. This is something I've seen other people implement in ASP.NET MVC 5. On the plus side, the library automatically includes navigation links to the pages in the breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest You to Use **breadcumb**. Its a bootstrap component you can manage it on front end. In Site map you have to do some extra work. As compare to sitemap, breadcumb  is simple , take little effort and you can customise it also 
[breadcomb](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#breadcrumbs)
please visit the above link it will be help full to you

Comment: I believe the question relates to handling breadcrumbs on the backend in ASP.NET Core. Bootstrap is just a frontend library.